# Spring MVC error with "NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got the below error.

Please give me some suggestions.

I am using `spring sts`.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebEnvironment;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: you need post your libraries

Comment: There is no actual question here. Consider adding the code or application context that creates the conditions for this error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use libraries that are incompatible. The code that is executed was compiled for one version of the spring API(ABI) but at run time there is a different version. Make sure you don't include different or newer versions of the same library into your application. This is quite an often case when applications are built with tools like Maven.

Comment: thanks :) it solved the issue. Am using STS 3.6.2 RELEASE, so am suppose to use jars with 3.2.3 RELEASE