# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()

Tags: java, spring, maven

I got the following error when trying to run maven project.

Error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebEnvironment;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 12, 2016 9:14:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet mvc-dispatcher
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebEnvironment;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>        
       /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
       /WEB-INF/data-source-cfg.xml
   </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security Filter -->
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

 <!-- Spring MVC -->
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>      
   <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="main.java" />
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<bean id="mongo"       class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
</bean>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
  <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
  <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Many solutions said that some jars could be missing although i have added most of them. What could be the possible reason for this error. Please give some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I had dependencies for spring-core, spring-web, spring-webmvc all of version 4.1.4.RELEASE. It was running just fine then. but to add mongodb to my code it showed error to add other jars too. So i ended up adding dependencies for spring-expression, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-context-support all of the same version 4.1.4.RELEASE. But now its generating the above mentioned error. Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like it's a dependency/version issue. Did you try googling your post title before you posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601279/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-web-context-configurablewebappl

Comment: Try running `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330318/spring-mvc-error-with-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Well i have all jars of the same version. And i found one link which i could relate to but got no solution. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095327/severe-exception-sending-context-initialized-event-to-listener-instance-of-clas]

Comment: M using sts plugin in eclipse. Any idea on how can i update spring or my pom.xml?

Comment: Open pom.xml in "dependency tree" mode in STS, type `spring` as filter and see if there are inconsistent dependency versions.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is executed was compiled for one version of the spring Api but at run time there is a different version.Make sure you don't include different versions of the same library into your application. When applications are built with tools like Maven this is quite common.

Comment: Well m using same version for all the jars. and how can i ensure if the problem is due to dependency/version?